# Making terminal buffer unlisted

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, buffers, terminal-buffer

I'm configuring my scripts to work with terminal in VIM and have a question regarding `:h special-buffers`. Among mentioned kinds there were the following:

```
unlisted    The buffer is not in the buffer list.  It is not used for
            normal editing, but to show a help file, remember a file name
            or marks.  The ":bdelete" command will also set this option,
            thus it doesn't completely delete the buffer.  Settings: >
            :setlocal nobuflisted

terminal    A terminal window buffer, see |terminal|. The contents cannot
            be read or changed until the job ends.
```

---

Currently I create a terminal buffer with the function

```
function! CreateTerminalInstance()
    execute "terminal ++hidden" 
    return bufnr("$")
endfunction
```

then stores the `bufnr` of the terminal and use it throughout the session.

The problem is when switching between buffers containing code to be displayed in some window with `:bnext` it sometimes displays the terminal in the window. This is because the terminal appears in the buffer list:

[image]

So I considered making this buffer with `:setlocal nobuflisted`, but it looks hacky since now the terminal buffer has two kinds: `terminal` and `unlisted` as I show above.

What is the preferred way to achieve switching between buffers corresponding to regular opened files?

Comment: I think `:set nobulisted` is the way to go here. BTW: I don't see, why this would look hacky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your function can be simplified into

```
let bufnr = term_start(&shell, {"hidden": 1})
```

Second, it's not a problem to have `buftype ==# 'terminal'` and `set nobuflisted` together, as these are two different options. So

```
if bufnr
    call setbufvar(bufnr, "buflisted", 0)
endif
```

is very much okay. However, the real question is: why you create a terminal at all if you are never going to show it? Maybe, you want `job_start()` instead?

Comment: I do have intention to show it. But I defined 2 functions: one for toggling and another one to make a terminal active (and therefore show if is not shown currently) each which uses the `CreateTerminalInstance` function.